# How to complete "Public Default Branch Includes 'Tournament of Beans.exe'"

Tags: steamworks-api

I'm trying to put my game on steam put the last thing is "Public Default Branch Includes 'Tournament of Beans.exe'". I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to finish this task.

[image]

Comment: What does it say when you hover over the `?` symbol? Does your repo contain the game exe?

Comment: It says " Your public branch must include all files referenced as launch options. These options are case sensitive." It contains Tournament of Beans, type Application.

Comment: Try a name that doesnt contain blankspaces and double check the spelling

Comment: You should configure your windows OS to display the file extensions of known types. You are coding with a computer that's not setup for coding.

Comment: I changed the .exe file to TournamentofBeans and put it in the Launch Options executable. But it still says I haven't done it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the build manifest of your public default branch. You'll see what files were uploaded to Steam and sometimes the executable has a weird name. For me it was [game].exe.exe so I just changed launch options to [game].exe.exe and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we had to put the exe and the main files on the "windows_content" folder... it seems that changed recently and we didnt notice

now you had to put the .exe and the files directly on the main folder *:\sdk\tools\ContentBuilder\content

i found this by myself
your welcome :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that it seems like the field is case-sensitive. So "game.exe" had to be instead "Game.exe".

Answer (score 0):

My issue for this was that my .zip contained a folder with my build, not JUST the build - I reizipped and amended the path and its fine now